# How to interrupt running Java process in Eclim?

Tags: vim, eclim

I'd like to code in Eclim, but there is one problem that troubles me. Sometimes there is a never-ending loop bug in my code. If I compile and then run then Eclim crashes. I tried the Ctrl-c command in Vim to interrupt the process, but it didn't work. I had to kill Eclim.

Are there any solutions to solve this problem or is it a problem with my settings in Eclim?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.Now I use the command "ps f" to find the running java process and kill it.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the process as background, just like `:!javac <args> <file> &`